# plot using pandas dataframe (help)

Tags: python, pandas

I need some help with repetitive tasks.
Now, I've constructed dataframe named 'merged', with
column names : "ind", 'tot_19M1", "myscore_19M1", "tot_19M2", "myscore_19M2"
my plan is to make barchart with pandas plot, 
putting ind as x, and rest of the column as ys

So far, I've tried

```
subdf1.plot(x="ind", y=["tot_19M1", "myscore_19M1", "tot_19M2", "myscore_19M2"], kind="bar")
```

I separated data using 'loc', because
dataframe has long lists of rows.

Now, I would like to 
use

```
subdf2 = merged.loc[5:9,:]
subdf3 = merged.loc[10:9,:]
subdf4 = merged.loc[15:14,:]
subdf5 = merged.loc[20:19,:]
subdf6 = merged.loc[25:24,:]
...
```

and plot again.

I think there would be better way.

Plus, I would like to ask How I would could simplify

```
subdf1.plot(x="ind", y=["tot_19M1", "myscore_19M1", "tot_19M2", "myscore_19M2"], kind="bar")
```

all i need is y every column except "ind"

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Can you share at least part of the data?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```py
x_col = "ind"
y_col = list(set(df.columns) - set(x_col))
subdf1.plot(x= x_col, y = y_col, kind="bar")
```

and if you tell us what you are indexing using 'loc', i would help you work simply.

Comment: thankyou. i’m using loc because since there are many rows in dataframes, i wanted to make 5 items in each bar graphs

Comment: 5 items mean just row index? Or is there any categories?